# PowerShell format Output same distance

Tags: powershell

Im trying to format the Output of my skript so you can get a better overview.
The Results are already correct but not quite pretty. Because of the different lenght of each Group Name even "`t" does nothing to make it look better. All I want is the True/False to be aligned.

Example:

```
WHfB              True
M365Outlook       False
M365-Admin        False
Mobile Apps       True
O365-Pilot        False
M365-Teams-User   True
```

My Code this far:

```
$UserID = Read-Host -Prompt 'UserID'

$GroupNames = @("WHfB","M365Outlook","M365-Admin","Mobile Apps","O365-Pilot","M365-Teams-User")

$Prompt = 'net user '+$UserID+' /domain'
$Result = cmd.exe /c $Prompt

echo "True  =`tMember of the Group;`nFalse =`tNO Member of the Group;`n`n"

ForEach ($item in $GroupNames){
$TrueFalse = [bool]($Result -match $item)
echo "$item = $TrueFalse"
}
echo `n`n
pause
```

Whats the easiest/best way to go about this?

Comment: There's probably powershell commands that do the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let PowerShell's built-in formatting subsystem do that work for you!

If you output 1 or more objects with 4 or fewer properties, PowerShell will automatically format them in a table for you:

```
$UserID = Read-Host -Prompt 'UserID'

$GroupNames = @("WHfB","M365Outlook","M365-Admin","Mobile Apps","O365-Pilot","M365-Teams-User")

$Prompt = "net user $UserID /domain"
$Result = cmd.exe /c $Prompt

foreach ($item in $GroupNames){
  [PSCustomObject]@{
    GroupName = $item
    IsMember = [bool]($Result -match $item)
  }
}

pause
```

Example output:

```
GroupName       IsMember
---------       --------
WHfB                True
M365Outlook        False
M365-Admin         False
Mobile Apps         True
O365-Pilot         False
M365-Teams-User     True
```

If you want to force the host application to render the table before reaching `pause`, you can pipe to `Out-Host`:

```
& {
  foreach ($item in $GroupNames){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      GroupName = $item
      IsMember = [bool]($Result -match $item)
    }
  }
} |Out-Host

# host application will now complete rendering of the output from the previous statement before pausing
pause
```

Comment: Stupid question, but how do I get the Output? If I replace the foreach loop with this I get no Output because it never gets echoed I guess?

Comment: You don't need `echo` - PowerShell will automatically redirect to standard output for you. I've update the answer with a complete example.

Comment: I copied it over and it still does not work for me. It asks for the UserID, prints a empty line and then pauses.  My PSVersion is "5.1.19041.4046". Might that be why it won't work for me? Im a beginner so there is a chance I'm missing something obvious here. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I just realized that it shows the result in PowerShell ISE after the Pause, if I run the script directly it closes after unpausing like it should. Why is it the result only show AFTER the pause? The pause is the last line in the scipt? What am I missing here?

Comment: @J0nsan - have you added the ```| Out-Host``` that MatthiasRJessen suggested? If not, you’re hitting an issue with “implicit write-output” delaying output by 300ms before it displays, so your ```pause``` is running before the output is shown. There’s a few questions on this site about that, but I can’t search right now to find one…

Comment: @mclayton Thanks for the hint! | Out-Host does not work for me. But I managed to find a "Workaround" by saving the foreach loop into a variable an then outputting it via $variable | Format-Table. I don't know how clean that is but it seems to work. Thank you MathiasR.Jessen for your help as well!